# Translating English Mother Quotes

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

I am getting a tattoo for my mother who passed 3 years ago.

I think any of the following would be beautiful:

“A mother/Your mother is always with you”

“A mothers love never dies”

“A mothers love lives on”

Or something of the sort. Any help would be inexplicably appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

A combination of your ideas and the translations in the other answer, fitted to [dactylic hexameter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dactylic_hexameter):

> *Matris amor numquam moritur — tecum est tua semper.*
> A mother's love never dies — yours is always with you.

Here "yours" refers to the mother, not to her love.

Comment: I'm sure your dactyls are much better Latin than any trochees I'm about to offer, but I think "Amor matris semper tecum" would work really well for a tattoo. Is the rearranged word order within the realm of "sensible" Latin?

Comment: And to the OP, I'm intending for that to translate to "A mother's love is always with you", which I'm hoping works for you.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Yes, *amor matris semper tecum* is perfectly valid Latin. That is a nice phrasing option to have, so do write it up as an answer!

Comment: Done, and thanks. Hope you don't mind that I relied on your imprimatur in the answer.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Not at all! I just gave your answer a vote.

Answer (score 3):

> Your mother is always with you.

Tua mater semper tecum est.

> A mother's love never dies.

Amor matris numquam moritur.

> A mother's love lives on.

Amor matris etiamnunc vivit.

Comment: I think "Tua Mater Semper Tecum" reads really nicely. How legit/illegitimate would it be to leave off the "est"?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I think removing "est" would make it unclear whether there should be "est" or "sit".

Comment: Sorry, I'm a Latin dummy who stumbled in here from Hot Network Questions. What would it mean with _sit_ instead of _est_?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Roughly: With *est* it's a statement (your mother is) and with *sit* it's a wish (may your mother be). Leaving either form of the verb implicit is fine if you're okay with the slight ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the translations provided by other answers, I'll offer

> *Amor matris semper tecum.*
> A mother's love is always with you.

I don't know how to properly conjugate or decline Latin, but this got a thumbs-up comment from one of the Latin pros here.

> Yes, *amor matris semper tecum* is perfectly valid Latin. - Joonas Ilmavirta

Hope you find something you like for your tattoo.